# Chomp (delete new line character at the end of string) in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any easy way to remove a new line character from a string in google spreadsheet?
A function returns a string with several words separated by new line character, but the it also returns a new line character at the end of string. I just want to delete the last character of the returned value.
I could only come up with something like below.
`=left(function(),len(function())-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding of your situation is correct, in this case, how about using `TRIM`?

```
=TRIM(A1)
```

- In this case, for example, when it supposes that the cell "A1" has `a1\nb1\nc1\n`, the result is as follows.

  [image]

#### Reference:

- [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)